# Retrieve mongo document same it shows in terminal

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

If i run a query through mongoTemplate using spring boot for the data present in collection I get end response as

```
{
    "_id": {
        "timestamp": 1597241082,
        "date": "2020-08-12T14:04:42.000+00:00"
    },
    "name": "Test Name",
    "createdDate": "2020-08-12T14:04:42.218+00:00",
    "updatedDate": "2020-08-12T14:04:42.218+00:00",
}
```

but I want to show end response like this

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f33f6fa36a1624b59db5310"),
    "name": "Test Name",
    "createdDate": ISODate("2020-08-12T19:34:42.218+05:30"),
    "updatedDate": ISODate("2020-08-12T19:34:42.218+05:30")
}
```

I have tried but no luck with below approch.

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("name").is("Test Name"));
mongoTemplate.find(query, Document.class,collectionName);
mongoTemplate.find(query, Object.class,collectionName);
```

Is there any way to achieve this ?

I know end response is not a valid JSONObject but I want to fetch it like this.

Comment: What is the query used?

Comment: @Gibbs edited my question.Please check

Comment: Can you show us the Document class? And how do you want to convert it to the response output?
You could write a custom .toString() method in that class, it's probably the easiest way to generate invalid json.

Comment: @Gibbs am using the library class org.bson.Document;
tried documents.toString();
output is Document{{_id=5f35030b6e426f1bf5f690d0, name=Test Name}}

Comment: I don't think spring-boot creates `ObjectId()` in response.